# Removing wp admin bar nodes for specific roles - $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'string' );

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to remove nodes from the wp admin bar (that displays in the front-end) for a specific role (shop manager). I successfully removed the nodes, but it is doing it for all the role types unfortunately.

I am referencing this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/remove_node/

I was able to remove the whole admin bar but the client wants something to move in and out of the back-end easily. I don't want them to have access to all the nodes.

I used a filter to remove the bar all together(which is not what they want). I tried using " `if ( current_user_can( 'shop_admin' ) ){` " with the node code above and keep getting errors.

```
//Hide Admin bar front-end

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function( $show ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'shop_admin' ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $show;
} );
```

So I had it like this:

```
 //Remove WP-Admin front-end Nodes

/**
 * Remove WP logo and comments from the Toolbar.
 *
 * @param WP_Admin_Bar $wp_admin_bar WP_Admin Bar instance.
 */
function wpdocs_remove_nodes( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    // Remove items from the menu bar.
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function( $show ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'shop_admin' ) ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'wp-logo' );  
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'comments' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'edit' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'litespeed-menu' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'theme-dashboard' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'customize' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new_draft' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'updates' );
    }
        return $show;
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpdocs_remove_nodes', 999 );
```

**Error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_action' (T_STRING), expecting ')'**

Thank you for your time!

Comment: OK so if the user has a role of `shop_admin`... Should the whole admin bar be hidden or only certain admin bar items should be hidden?

Comment: You are also missing two closing `}` in your second block of code.

Comment: @mikerojas I would like to keep the admin bar and have all nodes hidden except for the "Site Name" so they can click into the back-end.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact problem you are having? When you say you *"keep getting errors"*, that doesn't give us anything to go on :) You also include a block of code saying *"So I had it like this:"*... does that work or not work? If it doesn't work, what exactly is the problem? Can you update your question to include the error messages and the code you used that caused them? When we see the problem we might be able to help :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten My apologies for the confusion. I updated the error above and the code I was using. When I add  `add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function( $show ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'shop_admin' ) ) {` and try to remove the nodes from the role `shop_admin` it gives that error.  I want the administrator role to keep all the nodes and the shop admin (based off the shop manager role) to only show the "Site Name".  I am having trouble isolating the role to that function. Let me know if that makes better sense!

Comment: The issue was a just a syntax error which means you just had a mistake in your coding rather than any functionality. You usually get a line number with a syntax error that tells you were to look. Missing/mismatched/wrong quotes and brackets or missing semicolons are easy and common syntax errors so get used to looking for those first :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for identifying what causes the errors, from what @mikerojas identified, I was missing 2 `}` and I didn't need to use the filter. I will need to educate myself a bit more on when to apply filters and when not to. Also to better identify what the error messages are stating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need the extra filter `show_admin_bar` here so I updated the function to not use it.  This is also what is causing your error cause its not closed properly:

```
<?php
/**
 * Remove WP logo and comments from the Toolbar.
 *
 * @param WP_Admin_Bar $wp_admin_bar WP_Admin Bar instance.
 */
function wpdocs_remove_nodes($wp_admin_bar)
{
  // Remove items from the menu bar.
  if (current_user_can('shop_admin')) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('wp-logo');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('comments');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-content');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('edit');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('litespeed-menu');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('theme-dashboard');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('customize');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new_draft');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('updates');
  }
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wpdocs_remove_nodes', 999);
```

Comment: Thank you ! This solved the problem! I am still learning isolating roles, so I appreciate you going through this!

Answer (score 1):

For those look to use the USER ID's instead of ROLES. This works for me on a few sites I'm building, but I'm not sure if 100% perfect. Look for **ID, array(20158,35,15558)** and change the numbers to your own from the user section of your site.

**FINDING NODES:**
If your looking for your custom menu items, you can use the browsers "inspector" and search for (CSS) ID's  "*wp-admin-bar-*".

Find the (CSS) ID of your menu item, and add/replace from the list below. Don't forget to drop the "*wp-admin-bar-*" after you find  it.

So '*wp-admin-bar-MYTHINGY*' will now be '*MYTHINGY*'
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/remove_node/

P.S. changes to the code are welcomed if I missed something or other.

```
// Remove frontend admin bar items
function remove_admin_bar_items($wp_admin_bar) {

   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array($current_user->ID, array(20158,35,15558))) { //ID's of users

    
        // Plugin related admin-bar items
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('blocksy_preview_hooks');
        // WordPress Core Items 
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('updates');
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('comments');
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-content');
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('wp-logo');
        //$wp_admin_bar->remove_node('site-name');
        //$wp_admin_bar->remove_node('my-account');
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('search');
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('customize');
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_admin_bar_items', 999);
```